# Mujoco_py missing path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, physics, openai-gym

I am trying to get mujoco_py running. When I do

```
import mujoco_py
```

I get this error:
Exception:

```
Missing path to your environment variable.  
Current values LD_LIBRARY_PATH=  
Please add following line to .bashrc:  
export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/jonah/.mujoco/mjpro150/bin
```

I have added the above line to both /etc/skel/.bashrc and ~/.bashrc. If I run

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get

```
/home/jonah/.mujoco/mjpro150/bin/
```

My .mujoco folder includes mjkey.txt and the mjpro150 folder. I can run ./simulate successfully, so I have a feeling that this is some kind of mujoco_py specific bug.

Answer (score 2):

Which program do you use to import mujoco?

I had a similar issue using mujoco_py with PyCharm Community 2018.1. A workaround was to **launch** PyCharm **from the terminal** instead of using the launcher icon. Maybe it could help with your issue too.

Otherwise you could try adding the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`, as proposed in this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022836/python-not-recognizing-ld-library-path/1022913#1022913

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall Pycharm for the newest version.

Comment: Please use comments to give advice to asker

Answer (score 0):

After you save the .bashrc file your want execute this code.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now link is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the user which you run the code with. The mismatch user will cause this problem. There is the checklist may help you:

1. Don’t use ‘sudo’ to run the code;
2. Don’t use ‘sudo’ or virtual environment (e.g., anaconda) to run Pycharm (If you run the code in Pycharm).